# Find a non-trivial unit of the ring of integers of a specific cubic field.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

In particular, how to find a non-trivial unit of the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is a root of $y^3+3y-5=0$.

Note, since the constant term is $-5$, the norm of $\alpha$ is 5, thus $\alpha$ is not a unit.

So far, I can prove that a non-trivial unit is not in the form of $a\alpha+b$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: A superannuated mathematician with failing eyesight begs you not to use $a$ and $\alpha$ in the same formula.

Comment: @Lubin Sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(y-1)(y^2+y+4)=(y^3+3y-5)+1$$

Comment: Thanks, my computations are wrong...

Comment: Slick. I would have labored long and hard over this.